# nvim cannot save - E506: Can't write to backup file (add ! to override)

Tags: neovim

When I try to save a file I receive the error

> ```
> E506: Can't write to backup file (add ! to override)
> ```

It's working if I use `:w!`

I'm using neovim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:se backup? backupdir? backupext?
```

Use this comand to find the folder used for backups.

Then create the backup folder:

```
mkdir ~/.vim-tmp
```

Comment: What if the backup folder already exists?

Comment: Yeah. You saved my time. Thanks.

Comment: @Moberg refresh

Comment: @Abdusalammohamed what do you mean?